# Remove underscore in variable with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I remove all underscores in a string stored in a variable in bash?

I have currently a variable `myVar` which contains a string `foo1234_`. The underscore's position could however be anywhere else.

I want to remove the underscore, and have tried `myVar="${myVar//_}"`,but get `Bad substitution` output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is probably a trivial question. What efforts did you try? Can you show us the sample string the efforts made?

Comment: Question updated. I am new to bash, and am now learning the basics.

Comment: which unix/linux version are you using ?

Comment: Linux 4.13.0-26

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash` - not (for example) `sh`?

Comment: @steeldriver that was actually it, if I run it explicitly with `bash`, it works, but not with `sh`. I am new to bash scripting, hence I thought `sh` and `bash` were virtually interchangeable... Thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the substitution type of Parameter Expansion:

```
underscored=A_B_C
echo "${underscored//_}"
```

`//` replaces all the occurrences; if you replace by the empty string, you can omit the final `/`.

Comment: Trying that, I get `Bad substitution`

Comment: What version of bash do you use?

Comment: Problem solved, I was running `sh` and not `bash`

Answer (score 2):

This simple variable reassignment will do the trick:

```
myVar=${myVar//_/}
```

Output:

```
# myVar="hello_world__1"
# echo $myVar
hello_world__1
# myVar=${myVar//_/}
# echo $myVar
helloworld1
```

Comment: Trying that, I get `Bad substitution`

Comment: Problem solved, I was running `sh` and not `bash`